# Check if timeofday is in a specified range

Tags: .net, vb.net, boolean, timeofday

```
    Dim time As String = TimeOfDay.ToString("tt")
    Dim time2 As Integer = TimeOfDay.ToString("hh:mm:ss")
    If time = ("du.") Then
        timehre = (time2 + 12)
        Debug.WriteLine("munkaidoben")
    Else
        Debug.Write("munkaidoben = false")
        timehre = time
    End If

    For munkaido As Integer = 13 To 19

        If time2.ToString.Contains(munkaido) Then
            duplaar = False
        Else
            duplaar = True
        End If
    Next
```

Timehre is already declared as integrer.So,what i want,to get time in utc +1,and if time is in range of 13:00 - 19:00 then return a true boolean value,and if it is not in range of 13:00 - 19:00 then returning a false boolean value.

P.s. sorry for bad english,i hope you will understang my question.

Comment: I search for a certain string,because i dont know how to convert timeofday to utc +1 time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, turn on `Option Strict`:

```
Dim time2 As Integer = TimeOfDay.ToString("hh:mm:ss")
...
For munkaido As Integer = 13 To 19
    If time2.ToString.Contains(munkaido) Then
```

This is a good example of why not using `Option Strict` is a very bad idea for other than toy programs.  If the time is "10:45:23", the result in `time2` will be `49`!  Where did that come from?  It is the [ASCII value](http://www.asciitable.com/) of the first character in the string.

Later, the code will test if the text `"49"` contains 13 - 19 which can never be true. With the conversion that happens, `time2` can only ever be between`"48"` and `"57"`.  Syntactically, it is invalid because a string can never contain an integer.

Not using `Option Strict` can result in this type of unwanted conversion and bugs.  Don't leave the compiler to guess what you mean:
**Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults -> Option Strict On**

---

Your code is not really testing if the time is in a range, just whether 13-19 appear somewhere in the string.  If the minutes or seconds are one of those values, it will validate.

Dont use strings to do `DateTime` operations. The `DateTime` type has a full set of properties you can use:

```
Dim dt = DateTime.Now

If dt.Hour >= 13 AndAlso (dt.Hour <= 18 OrElse
                         (dt.Hour = 19 AndAlso dt.Minute = 0)) Then
    Return True
Else
    Return False
End If
```

The code tests if the *time* is between 13:00 AND 19:00 rather than just the hour, in order to detect 19:01 or 19:59 which *are* the 19th hr but the minutes put it after 19:00, the hours and minutes are checked.

I am not sure how UTC comes into play, but that is also easy using `DateTime` methods:

```
Dim dt = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()
```

To add an hour:

```
Dim dt = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime.AddHours(1)
```

Comment: The DateTime.Hour property returns an Integer. It calculates the number of hours since midnight and rounds down to the nearest integer. Therefore, if the time is 7.30pm, DateTime.Now.Hour will return 19 and the posted function will return True. However, 7.30pm is outside of the hour range 13 to 19 and therefore it should return False. In order to determine whether the time is within a certain hour range, the number of hours since midnight needs to be calculated as a Double.

Answer (score 0):

I had to achieve something similar recently. This is what I came up with.

```
Public Function GetHoursSinceMidnight(ByVal dDateTime As DateTime) As Double
    Dim myTimeSpan As TimeSpan = dDateTime - dDateTime.Date
    Return myTimeSpan.TotalHours
End Function

Public Function IsTimeInRange(ByVal dDateTime As DateTime, ByVal dStartTime As Double, ByVal dEndTime As Double) As Boolean
    Dim dTime As Double = GetHoursSinceMidnight(dDateTime)
    Return dTime >= dStartTime AndAlso dTime <= dEndTime
End Function
```

So to check if the current time is between 1pm and 7pm universal time plus one hour, call:

```
IsTimeInRange(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime.AddHours(1), 13, 19)
```

It will return True if the current time is between 1pm and 7pm and False if it is outside the range.